# Xamarin Forms Carousel Views - Android and iOS differences

Tags: xamarin.forms

I cannot get both platforms to exhibit the same behaviour

I want to show multiple items on screen at the same time

iOS appears to allow PeekAreaInserts to work like Margin, in that you can specify top, right, bottom, and left

Android only seems to acknowledge one value

This means as soon as I set a PeekAreaInsert value, the Android view renders itself with the first item in the middle of the page, whereas the iOS view can utilise this value but still be aligned to the left of the page

Is there a way to achieve consistent look and feel by having Android align with the start, or left, of the view when using the PeekAreaInserts value?

The following example left aligns a carousel view on iOS but the same code on Android centers the first item always

```
                <CarouselView.Margin>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="5, 0, 0, 0" />
                        <On Platform="Android" Value="0, 0, 0, 0" />
                    </OnPlatform>
                </CarouselView.Margin>
                <CarouselView.PeekAreaInsets>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="0, 0, 200, 0" />
                        <On Platform="Android" Value="200,0,0,0" />
                    </OnPlatform>
                </CarouselView.PeekAreaInsets>
```

Comment: We have a different behavior when using `PeekAreaInsets` on Android and iOS.
In iOS we always position each element in the center. For that reason, we leave space to the left of the first element or to the right of the last in some cases.
On Android, `PeekAreaInsets` is not adding that space to the beginning or the end. If you do want to achieve the same effect on iOS and Android , you would better use `CollectionView`  with Snap options .

Comment: OK, that works, thank you

Comment: I will post it as answer .Could you accept it ? Which will help more people:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cause:** We have a different behavior when using `PeekAreaInsets` on Android and iOS.

In iOS we always position each element in the center. For that reason, we leave space to the left of the first element or to the right of the last in some cases.

In Android, `PeekAreaInsets` is not adding that space to the beginning or the end.

**Workaround:**  If you do want to achieve the same effect on iOS and Android , you would better use `CollectionView` with **Snap** options (set it as **Start**) .

Comment: Is it possible to override this behavior ( for example using renderer ) for iOS ?